# get two or more values in an edit text and get the result from a button click

Tags: java, android-studio, calculator

I'm building a GPA calculator with android studio

**What I have:**

I have an edit text for credit unit and another for grade with different ID's

I  have  a method for the button

the app runs fine but when i input a value for the creditunit and a value for the grade, nothing happens when i click the button.

here is my xml

edit text for credit unit

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_credits"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ems="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="e.g. 0, 2, 3 "
        android:inputType="textPersonName|number|numberDecimal" />
```

edit text for grade

```
        EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_grade"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:ems="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="e.g. A, B, C "
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp" />
```

button

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:onClick="calcGpa"
            android:text="get gpa"
           android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>
```

here is my java

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditCreditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_credits);
        mEditGradeText =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_grade);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());

    }
    private View.OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                allCredits.add(mEditCreditText);
                allGrades.add(mEditGradeText);
            }
        };
    }




    public int pointPerSubj(int number,String grade) {
        int point;

        if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            point = 5;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
            point = 4;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
            point = 3;
        else if (grade.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
            point = 2;
        else
            point = 0;

        int perSubjectPoint = number * point;
        return perSubjectPoint;
    }

    public void calcGpa (View v) {

         gpa = perSubjectPoint/totalCredits;

        display(gpa);
        }


    // display method
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView gpaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpa_text_view);
        gpaTextView.setText("" + (number));
    }

    }
```

Comment: please add your code here only then we can help

Comment: "i have tried so many answers from this site but none seems to work" what are all those things you tried? What did not work exactly? Show us your code please and add the information on what you tried already.

Comment: please add your code here and also check the log and post the java error what you got..

Comment: i just updated the question,please take a look at my java and xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, else I would have asked for more code in the comments.

Your onClickListener adds your EditTexts to what I'm assuming are ArrayLists of EditTexts: **allCredits** and **allGrades**

In the first place, if you meant to insert the text, then those should be ArrayLists of strings, and you should be doing:

```
allCredits.add(mEditCreditText.getText().toString());
allGrades.add(mEditGradeText.getText().toString());
```

Also, your code does not indicate where any of your methods **calcGpa** and **pointPerSubj** are called.

> I believe you are simply not calling the required methods to display
>   anything.